# Fullcalendar calEvent.id to modal window

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i use the fullcalendar plugin, my Event Information appears in a modal window. But now i need an Admin Link to delete an event.

```
    $('#InfoTerminModal #eventTitle').html(calEvent.title);
    $('#InfoTerminModal #startDate').html(startDate);
    $('#InfoTerminModal #endDate').html(endDate);
    $('#InfoTerminModal #place').html(calEvent.place);
    $('#InfoTerminModal #place_detail').html(calEvent.place_detail);
    $('#InfoTerminModal #admin_vorname').html(calEvent.admin_vorname);
    $('#InfoTerminModal #admin_nachname').html(calEvent.admin_nachname);
    $('#InfoTerminModal #description').html(calEvent.description);
    $('#InfoTerminModal').modal('show');
```

Within the modal i have a simple link Delete" But i don't know how to get the Event.ID to my link!

Any suggestions for me?

Thanks in advance

Dennis

Comment: How do you assign event data to full calender? Can you show the code?

Comment: so we can help you with it.